# How to handle errors in async Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

Context: I have a rather large project which is a social media back end. We use MondoDB (w/ mongoose) and Express in JS. The question that I have is: Is it necessary to continue wrapping every route in try/catch blocks to ensure responses? Currently **almost** all (some need to return more specifc errors) of our routes look like this:

```js
router.get('/path/to/route', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // function of route
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: false })
    }
}
```

I suspect there may be something anti-pattern about the continual use of `try`/`catch` blocks **or** the use of `async` functions for every route. My idea was to simple make a standard error handler that sends the 500 response, but then I believe that `try`/`catch` would still be necessary to use `next(err)`

Overall:

- What about our code is anti-pattern?
- Should routes use async?
- Should `try`/`catch` blocks be continually used?
- What is the correct pattern?

If anyone has the time to response, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `try/catch` on every route. You can use middleware to catch handle all errors and respond with the appropriate status code. A short example is:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send({ status: false })
})
```

You can read more about error handling in Express [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest creating a errorHandler.js file in your project with these contents.

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
  }
}


 const handleError = (err, res) => {
  const { statusCode, message } = err;
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: "error",
    statusCode,
    message
  });
};

module.exports = {
  ErrorHandler, 
  handleError
}
```

Then in your api.index.js you register a middleware, after importing the exported members of your errorHandler.js file, like so.

```
import {handleError} from errorHandler.js;

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  handleError(err, res);
});
```

then each time you want to handle a potential error, import the ErrorHandler class from the ErrorHandler.js file, and then simply use this signature

```
import {ErrorHandler} from errorHandler.js;

if(somethingWentAwry){
     throw new ErrorHandler(400, "something went really awry")
 }
```

---

Since the handleError function, and its use as a middle-ware in api.index.js doesn't handle next, the chain ends when you throw an error.

The solution is inspired by Chinedu Orie's post [here](https://dev.to/nedsoft/central-error-handling-in-express-3aej)

Comment: Link only answers are undesirable. You should extract the core solution from linked page. If the only thing you do is quote, make sure it is placed inside a quote-block. This way people know that you didn't write it yourself (otherwise you will be downvoted for plagiarism) then add a reference to the original reading material somewhere in your answer. The reason for extracting the useful info is because the answer does not hold up if the link where ever to go down. If you don't feel like putting in the work and just want to leave a link, use a comment instead.

Comment: @3limin4t0r 
thankyou for your input. I have updated the answer accordingly.